# While making changes to the SSIS package, is it possible to keep the GUIDs stable?

Tags: sql-server, git, visual-studio, ssis

As a built-in mechanism, the Microsoft SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package [automatically assigns one GUID](https://sqlnuggets.com/specifying-a-value-for-an-ssis-packageid/) for every object in the package. As a result, a simple modification with Visual Studio updates all the GUIDs in the `.dtsx` source code file. And it looks messy and confusing if we use a source control, e.g., Git.

As an example, we modified a SQL query in the package, changing a select item

- from `x_forwarded_for`
- to `left(x_forwarded_for, 32) as x_forwarded_for` to get the substring of the first 32 characters. So, the meaningful difference is only the following two lines.

```
-  , `x_forwarded_for`
+  , left(x_forwarded_for, 32) as `x_forwarded_for`
```

However, the `.dtsx` source file has over 400 lines of differences as the GUIDs are updated. The partial diff sample below demonstrates what we have in the source control, and notice that the `DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"` and `DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"` values are different from one object to another.

**Our Question:**

- We wonder if there is a way to keep the GUIDs stable. And if they must be unique, we can update them before releasing the package to production.
- Just double-checking, we believe the UUIDs belong to the built-in mechanisms of SSIS, and we must have them in the source code. Are we correct on this point? Please kindly remind us if there is a way to do without the GUIDs in SSIS.
- We intend to improve SSIS with source control and highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

**Details:**

The sample partial diff on the `.dtsx` source code file after a small modification in the logic.

```
--- a/etl-package-sample-name.dtsx
+++ b/etl-package-sample-name.dtsx
@@ -1,2977 +1,2977 @@
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
   DTS:refId="Package"
   DTS:CreationDate="5/11/2020 4:59:57 PM"
   DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
   DTS:CreatorComputerName="WIN"
   DTS:CreatorName="Administrator"
-  DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+  DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
   DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
   DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="14.0.3026.27"
   DTS:LocaleID="1033"
   DTS:ObjectName="etl-package-sample-name"
   DTS:ProtectionLevel="2"
-  DTS:VersionBuild="47"
-  DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+  DTS:VersionBuild="48"
+  DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
   DTS:VersionMajor="0">
   <DTS:Property
     DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
   <DTS:ConnectionManagers>
     <DTS:ConnectionManager
       DTS:refId="Package.ConnectionManagers[Flat File Connection Manager]"
       DTS:CreationName="FLATFILE"
-      DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+      DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
       DTS:ObjectName="Flat File Connection Manager">
       <DTS:ObjectData>
         <DTS:ConnectionManager
           DTS:Format="Delimited"
           DTS:LocaleID="1033"
           DTS:HeaderRowDelimiter="_x000D__x000A_"
           DTS:ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="True"
           DTS:RowDelimiter=""
           DTS:TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_"
           DTS:CodePage="1252"
           DTS:ConnectionString="F:\work\recon\biml-eservices\error-flat.txt">
           <DTS:FlatFileColumns>
             <DTS:FlatFileColumn
               DTS:ColumnType="Delimited"
               DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_"
               DTS:DataType="19"
               DTS:TextQualified="True"
               DTS:ObjectName="entity_id"
-              DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+              DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
               DTS:CreationName="" />
             <DTS:FlatFileColumn
               DTS:ColumnType="Delimited"
               DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_"
               DTS:MaximumWidth="32"
               DTS:DataType="130"
               DTS:TextQualified="True"
               DTS:ObjectName="state"
-              DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+              DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
               DTS:CreationName="" />
             <DTS:FlatFileColumn
               DTS:ColumnType="Delimited"
               DTS:ColumnDelimiter="_x002C_"
               DTS:MaximumWidth="32"
               DTS:DataType="130"
               DTS:TextQualified="True"
               DTS:ObjectName="status"
-              DTS:DTSID="{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}"
+              DTS:DTSID="{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}"
  ...
  ...
  ...

   , `shipping_method`
   , `store_currency_code`
   , `store_name`
-  , `x_forwarded_for`
+  , left(x_forwarded_for, 32) as `x_forwarded_for`
   , `customer_note`
   , if(`created_at` &lt; timestamp('1753-01-01'), timestamp('1753-01-01'), `created_at`) as created_at
   , if(`updated_at` &lt; timestamp('1753-01-01'), timestamp('1753-01-01'), `updated_at`) as updated_at
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: it is the definition that they are unique, so if you don't need them why use them, it is basically a string and you can generate them manually as long as you make them unique yourself for the primary key

Comment: Are you familiar with [BIML](https://www.bimlscript.com/)? Among other things, it solves the problem you're having by making the BIML script the source and the SSIS package is a build artifact that you don't need to check in anymore.

Comment: Yes, we use Biml and BimlScript, and we used BimlScript to generate the above SSIS sample. BimlScript works well with source control, but we sometimes need to adjust the generated SSIS package manually; therefore, we still want to put the .dtsx file under source control. Also, the .dtsx file goes directly into the production, so it is always good to have it in source control.

Comment: Still, very good reminder, @BenThul, much appreciated. A workaround could be to convert the SSIS package into raw Biml text and then track the Biml file instead of the .dtsx file. We are still hoping for a more elegant solution, though.

Comment: For example, during development, we have many SSIS packages and often need to make a Git commit and use it as the last good point to roll back to. We remember the conversion from SSIS to Biml is currently a manual operation, so it is error-prone. With the indirect workaround, we would have to repeat this manual procedure frequently.

Comment: "we sometimes need to adjust the generated SSIS package manually" - is this out of expediency or is there some capability that BIML is missing? I would propose that the situation that you're in is somewhat dangerous insofar as you have BIML that _looks_ like it generates a given package but doesn't _actually_. And, as my people like to say, the only thing worse than no information is bad information.

Comment: For example, the logic change in the above example was a manual adjustment, changing `x_forwarded_for` to `left(x_forwarded_for, 32)` for debugging purposes. The SSIS ETL is part of our daily automatic report, so we are under time pressure to resume the function as soon as possible when it fails. It's too slow to go through the formal way of Biml generation, so we manually adjust it. The packages generated by BimlScript have a naming pattern, e.g., `etl-biml__xxxxxxx.dtsx`, and once manually adjusted, we will change the name to indicate it. Does this answer to our question here?

Comment: Per your original questions "Please kindly remind us if there is a way to do without the GUIDs in SSIS." - not so far as I know; SSIS was designed to manipulated with a GUI and as such any changes it makes within its internal format should be treated as opaque.

Comment: "We intend to improve SSIS with source control and highly appreciate any hints and suggestions." - it sounds like you know what the right thing to do is and are mostly doing it (i.e. BIML). You just need to commit to it. Break/fix will happen but you can't layer on top of that;. either integrate the change into your BIML or roll it back.